# How to make a Cube that cannot be 3d printed

Tags: 3d-printing

so recently i started using blender, i watched a tutorial on how to start with blender and the first thing the man did was make a base for his 3d prints in the software, so he just made a cube set the z to -1, and then went about so i did the same, but when i export my project, there is now a large cube that goes under it, i really like modeling on the cube, so my question is how do i make an object in blender, then make it so that model does not come out when it is exported

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. If you don't want a cube why do you add one? Please [edit] your question and show images that illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: So, I think what you're saying is that you're trying to make something 3D printable, and many projects require you to model the "base" of the print area, but not export it. One person achieved this by keeping it below 0 on the Z axis, but that isn''t working for you? If you need the base to visualize the project, but don't want to export it, you could always delete the "base" before exporting (remember to save your file first so you can "bring it back" if needed). Alternatively, most export formats offer the option of exporting selected objects only - just make sure to not have it selected.

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherBennett , you have (somehow) understood exactly what i mean, sorry for the messing wording in my original post, and i will do what you said!